# how to get the unique id of array element on click through angularjs from firebase database

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

```
HTML: 
 <div ng-controller="getIdController">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <hr />
                    <table class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Name</th>
                                <th>Age</th>
                                <th>Gender</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr ng-repeat="user in userData">
                                <td> {{ user.name }} </td>
                                <td> {{ user.age }} </td>
                                <td> {{ user.gender }} </td>
                                <td><button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="getObjectId()">Get Id</button></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table> 
                </div>
            </div>   
        </div>   
</div>
```

App Js:

```
var crudApp = angular.module('crudApp', ['firebase']);
crudApp.controller('getIdController', ['$scope', '$firebaseArray', function($scope, $firebaseArray){

    var ref = new Firebase('https://blistering-fire-4719.firebaseio.com/users');

    $scope.userData = $firebaseArray(ref);    

    $scope.getObjectId = function(){

        $scope.userData.$loaded()
            .then(function(id){ 

            var obj = id;

            console.log(obj);          

        });
    }   
}]);
```

Explanation:

Ok here In firebase i have User table and it has 3 objects each with unique id. Currently I am trying to extract the unique id for object on click of Get Id button in html. But the problem is if I do console.log(id) the function getObjectId() gives me //Array [ Object, Object, Object ].. clicking on object takes me to its data and it has $id as -K9jyc0K9i28h53d23Uw..

Is there any way to get the unique id for a particular element on clicking the button

I want this unique id to be shown for element on clicking a particular element/object in html.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your user object has the id property on it, you can just refer directly to that.  You can pass it as a parameter from your ng-click directive:

```
<button ng-click="selectUser(user)">
```

and in your controller:

```
$scope.selectUser = function(user) {
    console.log(user); // should emit the user object.  is id a property?
}
```

If all of your objects use the same property, you can have a single function:

```
$scope.showObjectId = function(object) {
    alert(object.id);
}
```

Comment: User is a table name with 3 entries in array as object...object has $id now when i click on a particular object in array it should extract the $id value that is string in a variable and give back to the controller.. so i can use it in controller for furthe manipulation.. how to do tha?

Comment: thanks... but if i have the object how can i do manipulations on this like delete update etc

Comment: What about the case when i have no id?

Answer (score 0):

You can show the id in the html like this (within the ng-repeat):

```
<td> {{ user.$id }} </td>
```

Or send it to the ng-click function (within the ng-repeat):

```
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="getObjectId(user.$id)">Get Id</button> //Just send the id to the function
<button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="getObjectId(user)">Get Id</button> //Send the etire user object to the function
```

And in you javascript you can use it like this:

```
$scope.getObjectId = function(user){ 
//If you only send the id to this function you can get the entire user object like this (it gives a $firebaseObject i think):
var user = $scope.userData.$getRecord(user);
//Here you can do anything with the user
//Update user data
$scope.UserData.$save(user);
//Remove user
$scope.UserData.$remove(user);
}
```

Comment: How can i use it back in my controller as a scope to further manipulate the data for deleting and editing etc.

Comment: Updated the answer. Feel free to ask questions if i'ts not clear yet.

Comment: If i take user.$id it will give me the complete array with three objects in it but if i do user[0].$id then it will give me the id for first object..actually i want the object id for particular object that i click in html but do not want to give the index of object as it should get automatically when i click GetId button and send the id back to controller

Comment: Do you have the button inside the ng-repeat in the HTML? When you use it inside the ng-repeat (so each user has his own button) it should give the id of the user you click.

Comment: by ading this ......var user = $scope.userData.$getRecord(user); console.log(user) gives //null....